# placing bitmaps on matplotlib plot

Tags: python, bitmap, matplotlib

I am creating plots on which I need to place small bitmaps at a given
location with a given size (ships, navigational markers, and some 
results of my analysis). I was unable to force imshow() dropping my 
bitmap in the right place, and the examples with add_patch() do not 
show anything like I need. Can it be done what I need? If so, how?

Thank you

Comment: I fixed it by creating a large image and dropping the small images on there: An image is an array and it is trivial to replace a slice.